# I am still vulnerable to spectre and meltdown

Tags: 16.04, updates, security

I found [this](https://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker) script on GitHub that checks whether you susceptible to spectre and meltdown. Due to this script I am still susceptible. But I read that Ubuntu 16.04 got all patches on 9-th January. I use

```
Linux 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

UPD:
I've done all `apt update/upgrade` magic but my kernel version is 4.13.0-26-generic. I've tested it on 2 machines. The update server is set to main server. Does anybody know why I do not see the latest kernel version?

UPD (about duplicate): It's not about official status of fixing this vulnerabilities on Ubuntu. It's about why I cannot install patches

Comment: That kernel was supposed to be the first for 16.04 released to patch for it.  What does `awk '/bugs/ {print ;exit}' /proc/cpuinfo` return?   I am running now 4.13.0-30-generic and it returns on that command:  `bugs  : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2`

Comment: @Terrance your command returns `bugs  : cpu_insecure`

Comment: @Terrance I just run `apt update, apt upgrade and apt-get dist-upgrade` but it says there is nothing to do

Comment: @Terrance, done, but nothing changes for me

Comment: @Terrance of course. I have even done reboot after it

Comment: @Terrance I do not use 4.10. My kernel version is 4.13.0-26-generic. The most strange thing why it is not 4.13.0-30-generic as on your computers.

Comment: 4.13.0-29-generic & now -30 are only in xenial -proposed repo, not yet released to main

Comment: @doug thanks a lot, you rock. Do you know when it will be moved to main?

Comment: No idea . People should only use -proposed selectively, ie. enable, update a specific package, disable. Though then they need to remember what they got from proposed. In this case you could get the new (-30) kernel, then disable -proposed & go on your merry way. However there is no imminent   exploit/attacks around so I'd just let the updates come to you thru normal repos.. as there is a small chance the new kernel could cause issues for some..